# Point external website to a url on my domain

Tags: domain, subdomain

I have a website hosted at www.example.com and a client that wants to point a subdomain of his to our website.

i.e. if someone visits subdomain.foo.com, then this automatically points to www.example.com/foo

This shouldn't be done via a redirect - i.e we want a visitor to subdomain.foo.com to remain on that url, even if they navigate further into the site.

I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search term is "reverse proxy".

This will need to be configured on the web server of the client.

An Apache configuration would look something like:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.foo.com:80>
ServerName subdomain.foo.com
ProxyPass        / http://www.example.com/foo
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.example.com/foo
</VirtualHost>
```

An nginx configuration would look something like:

```
server {
  server_name subdomain.foo.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com/foo ;
  }
}
```

Of course, what you wind up with will be determined by the client's server software, plus whatever would need to be done with those configuration options, including other directives to pass HTTP headers along, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure what you want can be achieved with a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) setup. For example, Apache uses [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to achieve this.

There are also many sites on the web that explain in detail how to set up a reverse proxy. I just can't really recommend a specific one.